# Can't open application from unidentified developer

Tags: macos

I'm using macOS Sierra and I can't open an application because it's from an unidentified developer. I went into my Security and Privacy settings and clicked on "open anyway" but **it still doesn't let me** open the app. How do I open an app from an "unidentified developer"?

Comment: Does right-click, Open work?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, was worth a try. I'm not on Sierra yet, so I hope someone else knows

Comment: That's how it's done on Sierra.  I have Sierra and it works every time for me if I right-click and select Open.

Comment: In Sec & Priv, you've selected "Allow apps downloaded from:" **Anywhere** ?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger MacOS Sierra does not have the "Anywhere" option.

Comment: @narawagames My copy of Sierra does. Are you running as Admin? That might make a difference.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yes, I am admin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a terminal command for this. I don't remember using it, and never wrote it down in my Sierra tweaks file. However:

`sudo spctl --master-disable`

From OSXDaily: [How to Allow Apps from Anywhere in macOS Sierra Gatekeeper](http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/27/allow-apps-from-anywhere-macos-gatekeeper/)

Comment: Works up through Big Sur. 2021

Comment: Works on macOS 13 Ventura

Answer (score 9):

you can do this with terminal

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/application.app
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General
Look for "Allow applications downloaded from" and set it to Anywhere

Hope this helps!

Comment: The item "Anywhere" is only visible in Sierra after entering `sudo spctl --master-disable`.